# What do you put in the parentheses of mysql_insert_id()?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-insert-id

I tried setting a variable like this: `$test_id = mysql_insert_id($dbc);` because I wanted to get the id of the last row inserted. I am able to connect to the database and insert the row but the next line (setting $test_id) it says this: `supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource` . Any ideas?

Here's the code:

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$q = "INSERT INTO tests (user_id, title, subject, creation_date) VALUES ('$user_id', '$title', '$subj', NOW())"; //query to insert test details into tests table
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
$test_id = mysql_insert_id($dbc);

if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) {//if the query ran correctly and the test details were added to the database

$q = "INSERT INTO content (test_id, field1) VALUES ($test_id, '$content')"; //query to insert test content into content table
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
```

$dbc is defined like this:

`$dbc = @mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);`

Comment: show us full source code, this is to less to give you good solution

Comment: @Svisstack and @kjy112 code posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments:
Oh, I see now. You're mixing mysql_* with mysqli_* functions. Those are different libraries. They don't mix. Use mysqli_insert_id() instead.

Comment: The example in the PHP manual illustrates this quite nicely: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: I tried that, but it told me that a connection could not be established.

Comment: Oh, I see now. You're mixing mysql_* with mysqli_* functions. Those are different libraries. They don't mix.

Comment: Use mysqli_insert_id() instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the link identifier (the output of `mysql_connect()`, not `mysql_query()`)

`mysql_insert_id` implicitly calls `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` which is session-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can leave out that parameter; it will know that you have a database connection open. If you want to specify the connection, use the return value from `mysql_connect`:

```
$dbc = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');

// later
echo mysql_insert_id($dbc);
```

Again, this is normally not necessary.

Also keep in mind that `mysql_insert_id` will only work after you've made an `INSERT` query where an index column with `AUTO_INCREMENT` was incremented. It will **not** return the latest ID that was inserted at some other time before the current session. For that you you could for example do:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM some_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using a MySQLi resource in a MySQL function (note the missing `i`).  There are 2 different extensions there.  If you're using `mysqli`, don't switch to `mysql`.  So just change that function to [`mysqli_insert_id($dbc);`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)